# How to inject javascript file to html string coming from api?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a html string which comes from the api.
I need to inject a static javascript file present in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WKUserScript and append the javascript to webview using the WKWebViewConfiguration.

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
guard let scriptPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js"),
let scriptSource = try? String(contentsOfFile: scriptPath) else { return }
let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
contentController.addUserScript(script)
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
self.view.addSubview(webView)

webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```